# Entity field query pager only loads first page

Tags: 7, entities, database

How do I load any page other than the first page with [Entity Field Query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x) pager?

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'event')
  ->pager(4)
  ->execute();
```

This returns the first 4 nodes. If i have 12 nodes, how do I return page 2 nodes 4-8 or page 3 nodes 8-12.

[The documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3Apager/7.x) states I can only pass `$limit` and `$element`. Have I missed something? What's the point of a pager that only loads the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some pointers:

- The query looks fine
- Try adding the parameter `?page=1` to your request and you should see different items. Page `0` is the one you see by default.
- You need to display the pager object while building your output, like:
  `$output['pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager');` This will make the pager visible and allow users to click on back/next buttons to navigate through pages to see other items which are not on the current page.